# Optimise Reverse LIKE query in mysql

Tags: mysql, indexing

We have table with only one column named `number`. It contains blacklist numbers.
For example if any record have `12345` numbers then all numbers starting with `12345` will be blacklisted, here `123456789` will be blacklisted.
for this we are using below sql query

```
select number from table WHERE '12345679' like concat(number,'%')

number
===
12345
1234587
98708293
```

I think this query does not use any index, so i was looking to optimize this query

Comment: Are you using it in a join with some other table? It should be able to use the index on the column in the other table.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to optimize searching of the blacklist table.

Comment: no, this is single standalone query

Comment: Explain statement will tell you if the query uses or could use an index.

Comment: If you are treating `123456789` as a string, please don't call it a "number".  It is confusing the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the query to:

```
SELECT number
FROM table
WHERE number IN ('1', '12', '123', '1234', '12345', '123456', '1234567', '12345679')
```

and create an index on `number`.

If you're performing the query from a programming language, it should be able to create the `IN` list dynamically using a loop on the input string. If you're doing it entirely in MySQL, you can do it in a stored procedure.